# Fantasy story 1982-1984

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

It's a series of Books I read while in the Marine Corps from 1982-1984. The main character was named Falcon or Falco, he was a captain of a mercenary band of soldiers that were sell-swords. He was a black Haired man that was struck by lightning giving him a white forelock. He starts out as a simple soldier but by acts of valor is promoted throughout the series of books. at some point he is released from service to the "Lord" and forms his own band/unit of men and continues to gather followers until he is captain of a independent army who travel mainly by horse and wagons selling their services to the highest bidder. Set in a feudal type society. I believe there were about half a dozen books maybe more in the series.

Comment: I am not sure it is on topic. Please give more details that can help associating the story with science fiction or fantasy genre (eg. magic, extraordinary creatures, superpowers, etc.)

Comment: getting struck by lightning and hair turning white is a trope: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PowerDyesYourHair, feudal society, seems likely that there are fantasy elements underneath that havent been stated yet. Voting to reopen

Comment: Better tropes would be http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LockedIntoStrangeness and http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SkunkStripe, since this is a single lock and it's permanent.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this doesn't appear to be about Science Fiction or Fantasy